# Can I uses an alias instead of the schema name?

Tags: alias, vespa

Is it possible in Vespa to use an Alias instead of the actual schema/document name when doing queries?
A similar feature to what we have in [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html)

Instead of doing:

`select * from source_name where title contains "foobar"`

We could do:

`select * from source_alias where title contains "foobar"`

This would allow decoupling of our indexing and querying logic.
A practical example is when we want to create a new schema, if we use an ALIAS, after everything is ready (i.e., finished deploying and indexing documents), we just change the ALIAS to point to the new schema. The serving doing the queries doesn't need to know anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's not possible to do it exactly as I was asking.

But there is an alternative way:

Since in Vespa, a lot of schema changes are possible without reindexing, and [field alias](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/schema-reference.html#alias) is a thing, what we can do is use an alias for the field(s) and when you need to do blue/green, you can add new fields and then switch the alias to point to the new field(s).

It can be a bit more messy if you need to change a lot of fields and it won't work if you need to change the ranking profile too.

Comment: Good idea! Still, I'm convinced from your description above that we should have support for schema aliases, so I'll be adding that.